# Parse Swift Update Errors

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

After the recent Swift update, I have been trying to debut a few lines of code and don't seem to be understanding what's wrong..

The lines are

```
 PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
```

with the error message "Cannot invoke 'geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground' with an argument list of type '((PFGeoPoint", NSError!) -> Void)'"

The second line is

```
 PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username:usernameTextField.text, password:passwordTextField.text, target: self) {
```

With the error "Extra argument 'target' in call"

I've tried looking online and debugging these, but I honestly have no idea what's going on. It seems to be an error in the parse code and I'm not sure why that is...

Edit: I fixed second error I was having. code:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextField.text, password:passwordTextField.text) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from Swift 1.2, the [Failable Casts](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22) is introduced. you can use the `PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` method like the following:

If you're quite sure that the downcasting will succeed, you can use `as!` to force the cast:

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
    (point:PFGeoPoint!, error:NSError!) -> Void in   
    if (error == nil) {
        println(point)
     } else {
        println(error)
     }             
}
```

If you're not sure if the casting will succeed, just use the `as?` operator. By using `as?`, it returns an optional value, but in case the downcasting fails, the value will be nil.

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
    (point:PFGeoPoint?, error:NSError!) -> Void in  
     if (error == nil) {
        if let myPoint = point {
           println(myPoint)
        }
     } else {
        println(error)
     }          
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw it! Thank you!